# Review queue showing review alert for users who can't review

Tags: discussion, bug, status-deferred, review-queues, review-suspension

I made a mistake in the review queue some days ago and I have to wait two more days to continue helping with the review queues. Fair enough.

But this red alert box keeps showing to me, reminding me of my failure:

[image: Image of review queue being empty but showing notification]

It appears to be saying:

> We desperately need your help! Our review lines are overflowing! Please... oh wait, it is you. Never mind, we don't want your help, go away.

Can't we just not show this alert for people who can't review?

Comment: Nah, we just like to remind you over and over again that you made a mistake. Welcome to SO curating, the most thankless job in the world ...

Comment: Oh yeh. I wrote a [question about this a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302093/please-dont-red-alert-me-for-queues-ive-handled). It would show when you'd run out of reviews as well. Like hey we're still overloaded, too bad you cannot help..

Comment: The "go away" part is a bit mean to me.

Comment: It might help if it reminded you how many days left you are in the red. Or let you view the queue totals in a read-only mode. But instead, its just a weird distraction that has no information.

Comment: same problem man. Its like, everyday, stack wants to remind me, that I am not welcome. and its hard to just ignore a notification dot, so its 10 seconds every time I log in.

Comment: We are going to dig into this one in a future sprint since it looks like this is still an issue. I updated the status to deferred.