# It looks like I have been suspended for one review, could someone explain how this happened?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

It looks like I have been suspended for one review, could someone explain how this happened?

**A link to the review that caused your suspension:**

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/27421468

**An explanation of why you made the choice you did:**

From my point of view I reviewed the post and seen that another [reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542251/liam) had already given two comments only a couple of hours prior asking the poster to update the question, I selected 'No action needed' as it appeared someone had already done something and didn't seem appropriate to hound the new user with moderator comments.

I am not against a learning curve and being helped to understand how to review but at the same time suspending someone for one review when I think suspension is intended for [multiple posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suspensions) seems heavy handed and not the way to help someone to get better.

I will admit I am trying to only review comments for which I have a technical understanding as it is difficult to understand if a post is written well if you have no technical knowledge of the subject, however this is not one of those cases.

**Update:**

Thanks for the dicussion on this it has helped, I understand that I did not review this one correctly.

While I might not agree with a 2 week ban, I think I can also see I am not naturally suited to reviewing but I will try my best to help with answers instead.

Comment: It's *never* just one...

Comment: Just because a comment has been made doesn't mean that all deserving actions have been taken. Also, Liam is not a moderator, he/she is just another user like you. In this case you should have flagged the question as unsalvageable so that it gets closed, rather than choose "No action needed".

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ok fair enough, also I am aware that these people are new to stackoverflow and so want to be welcoming and give them time to resolve issues with their post. Also in your opinion do I need a 2 week ban to learn that?

Comment: There's no requirement that you comment on a post that need to be closed. The only requirement is that you raise an appropriate close flag on it. Since someone else already commented on what the post author needs to do, you are right to not add another comment. However, commenting on a post that needs to be closed is just informing the post author. Nothing more. Even if the "I'm Done" button gets activated from you commenting, you're not "Done" on such a post.

Comment: I read these when I first got started: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/), [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/) and [How does the Triage queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/) and I went through all the pages in the help center about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)..
and [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).. Understanding what's in those posts and pages will help you review better :)

Comment: "I think I can also see I am not naturally suited to reviewing but I will try my best to help with answers instead". Being better at reviewing will also make you better able to pick Questions that will not get closed or deleted, so it's not a waste of time reading about it. However, not reviewing is likely to save you both time and trouble :)

Comment: The review you linked was neither an audit nor in the Triage queue (@Scratte). It appears that the moderator (who subsequently closed the question) feels that you need alerting to the fact that it was a *particularly* bad review. You can wait for that moderator to respond to this question, or maybe ask/plead for mercy/absolution in [his dedicated chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208985/bad-stack-overflow-reviews).

Comment: @AdrianMole  I agree it wasn't the right response now, we can close this one off as I think we have the right answer.

Comment: If you find the icon and "red dot" annoying, you can add this to your uBlock Origin `stackoverflow.com##.review-button-item.-item`

Comment: @Scratte not sure what you are referring to?

Comment: The icon on the top bar will show a red dot when it wants you to review. You can see an image of it in [Review queue showing review alert for users who can't review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389434/review-queue-showing-review-alert-for-users-who-cant-review). The information in the drop down has been changed now with [Make it more obvious that you're review banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351386), so users are informed, but I suspect the red dot still appears. If you have the adblocker "uBlock Origin", you can easily disable the icon.

Comment: I see what you mean, it just has some text now when you click on the icon which says you are suspeneded but no red dot unless it appeared initally when I clicked it first time and disappeared.

Comment: so...should we delete this one now? Not sure where the balance of historical record vs asked and answered lies?

Comment: @will - This question isn’t eligible to be deleted.

Comment: Looks like I can delete and there are 2 votes for it be deleted as well, which is why I ask 

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The review was definitely incorrect. The OP asks a debugging question without including code.

I do understand the desire not to "pile on" a new user (which I agree with), but "No action needed" means that *no one* needs to take action. If you think that you, personally, didn't need to take action on it, the appropriate thing to do would be to just skip the review entirely.

I might be missing something, but I can't tell whether this was a manual ban or an auto-ban. That being said, are you sure that you didn't miss any other review audits recently? If it was an auto-ban, you would have had to fail multiple review audits recently - you wouldn't be auto-banned for failing a single audit.

**Edit:** It seems like this was a manual review, so I assume that whatever moderator reviewed the post didn't agree with the review for the reason listed above.

Comment: Auto bans only occur with failed audits, right? So this was manual, since it wasn't an audit.

Comment: I think I failed 1 of the auto reviews last week.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Would it say that it was an audit if we just click on the link? I'm actually not sure about that. If it wasn't a review audit, it would have had to have been a manual review ban, though.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Yes, it does. It'll say "Review audit passed..." or "Review audit failed..." on audit tasks.

Comment: Casting a close vote/flag isn't "piling on"...

Comment: @CodyGray True - I think that the OP was talking about piling on with more comments though, plus flagging something that someone else already VTC doesn't really help because the close vote already sends it to the close vote queue.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica <3K users cannot see if there are close votes on a post unless they ask the API. Even if there is a close vote on it, the voter may retract.

Comment: Oh yeah. Leaving comments is almost entirely pointless, whether someone else has left one or not. Only leave a comment if you have something *specific and detailed* to say that isn't already conveyed by the close reason you've chosen (or plan to choose).